# Flowable multiinstance completion condition being called twice on false

Tags: flowable

Im using a combination of **cardinality** and **completion condition** to achieve multi instance (**parallel**) executions.
In cardinality field i have passed “**${someBean.multiInstanceCardinality(execution)}**”, This returns an integer value at runtime

In completion condition, I have passed **${someBean.multiInstanceCompletionCondition(execution)}**. This returns either true (if i want to terminate other instances and end multi instance) or false if i want the instance to go on.
However whenever i return false, the method **${someBean.multiInstanceCompletionCondition(execution)}** is called again by flowable. When I return true however, the method is not called again.  I want this method to be only called once once a task is completed. Am i missing something here? Im using flowable version 6.8.0.